Set timeout in a http.post call using typescript
I created one API call which is working fine with the following code:

  timeoutTime : number = 10000;

      this.http.post(this.apiUrl+'/login', JSON.stringify(data), {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json').set('language', this.translate.getDefaultLang()),
      }).pipe(timeout(this.timeoutTime))
      .subscribe(res => {                                                           
        resolve(res);
      }, (err) => {
        if (err.status == 408 || err.status == 0 || err.status == 503 || err.name == 'TimeoutError'){                                                           
          reject(this.getTimeoutResponse());
        } else {                                                           
        }
      });                                                           
    });
  }

The issue is:
That part it not working
.pipe(timeout(this.timeoutTime))

The timeout is not being set.
This is an angular app using Ionic and the default timeout is close to 5 seconds, I am trying to change it to 10.
Thanks

It looks like the backend is timing out after 5 seconds. In this case, you have no chance to increase the timeout on frontend side.

Hello @JSONDerulo, my test was turning off the server and making the post call. So the 5 seconds is in the frontend, not the backend.

In this case, there is probably something else in your app which triggers the timeout, such as an interceptor. If there is an existing timeout, you cannot increase it.

According to the documentation:
timeout Errors if Observable does not emit a value in given time span.
In more clear words: Timeouts on Observable that doesn't emit values fast enough.
https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timeout
What you are looking for is:
delay Delays the emission of items from the source Observable by a given timeout or until a given Date.
https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/delay
So the corrected code is:


.pipe(delay(this.timeoutTime))



